# Selecting users who are in the same group with "name"

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
Users
id  username
1   ryan
2   mike
3   annie
4   lisa 

Groups
id  name
1   football
2   hockey

Permissions 
user_id group_id           
1          1
1          2
2          1
4          2
```

So I'm looking for every username, who belong to at least one same group with username ryan. I'd also like to know everyone who is not in the same group.

```
SELECT Users.username
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Permissions ON Users.id = Permissions.user_id
LEFT JOIN Groups.id = Permissions.group_id
WHERE Users.id;
```

So this is how I got it started, but have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
with ug as (
      SELECT u.username, g.name
      FROM Users u JOIN
           Permissions p
           ON u.id = p.user_id 
     )
SELECT DISTINCT ug.username
FROM ug
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ug ug2
              WHERE ug2.group_id = ug.group_id AND
                    ug2.username = 'Ryan'
             );
```

The above assigns the group name to each user and then treats this as a single table.  `EXISTS` is used to determine if the groups overlap.

Note that `groups` is not needed because you are not asking for the name of the group.  The id is sufficient to answer the question.

I am not a big fan of using `select distinct`.  It usually means that the database engine is doing more work than necessary -- creating duplicates *and then* removing them.

Here is an alternative solution that uses `exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from permissions p join
                   permissions pr
                   on pr.group_id = p.group_id join
                   users ur
                   on pr.user_id = ur.user_id and
                      ur.username = 'Ryan'
              where p.user_id = u.id
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiple joins of Users and Permissions:

```
select uu.username
from Users u
inner join Permissions p on p.user_id = u.id
inner join Permissions pp on pp.group_id = p.group_id
inner join Users uu on pp.user_id = uu.id and pp.user_id <> u.id
where u.username = 'ryan'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hevnTxPvsee6KCd5vh7DvH/0).
Results:

```
| username |
| -------- |
| mike     |
| lisa     |
```